# SUM with left join returning incorrect result

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables

1. Calls
2. Amount

I'm trying to left join both the tables to get the sum total of amount along side volume/date.

Below is the query I'm trying, however getting very huge amount as result.

```
SELECT
    PeriodDate, SUM(Volume), SUM(Amount)
FROM
    Calls
LEFT JOIN
    Amount ON Calls.PeriodDate = Amount.PeriodDate
GROUP BY
    PeriodDate
```

[image]

Comment: Also a left join joins every possible row from the left table with every possible row from the right table. So if you have 3 times "6feb" in the left table and three times "6feb" in the right table, you get a total of nine rows in the join, which of course leads to wrong sums. The only way is, as @theimpaler suggested, do the aggregation separately on the respective tables and the join the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
select a.*, b.amount
from (
  select perioddate, sum(volume) as volume from calls group by perioddate
) a
left join (
  select perioddate, sum(amount) as amount from amount group by perioddate
) b on b.perioddate = a.perioddate
```